# Prop shows in Dev tools but shows undefined when used

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, prop

I'm passing a simple ID down to a child component but have an undefined console log error and cannot use the prop

I pass the prop here to the child

```
<transactions v-show="active_tab == 2" :userId="affiliate.user_id"></transactions>
```

Which is then picked up in the child here

```
props: ["userId"]
```

I then just try and console log the prop like so

```
console.log(this.userId);
```

As you can see from the image the prop is showing up in Devtools
[image: Prop is showing here]

Error is as follows

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "userId". Expected String with value "undefined", got Undefined

Comment: Please post the error, as well as other relevant code. Currently we dont know where any functions are being called.

Comment: Your casing is wrong. Use `:user-id="affiliate.user_id"`

Comment: this may be a race issue, don't know where you get your id from but try `:userId="someConstant"` see if that works.
In that case you can try a few things one option would be to condition the rendering of the child component on the prop having a value:
`v-if="affiliate.user_id"`

Answer (score 2):

Try use the call on template like this:

```
<transactions v-if="active_tab == 2" :user-id="affiliate.user_id"></transactions>
```

The vue compilation can change camelcase props on template to lowercase with hyphen.

You can take a look on vue documentation about that: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Answer (score 1):

So it would seem the prop was being declared after page load, So I have used a Watch to wait for the change and then run the method

as so

```
watch: {
    user_id() {
      console.log(this.user_id);
      this.fetch_transactions_data();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively, use conditional rendering on your component to wait for the value, eg `<transactions v-if="affiliate.user_id" :user-id="affiliate.user_id"...`